# Google sheet query to combine values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

From various examples I've hacked together a pretty neat aggregation function which gives me an overview on which activity (strings in G) I've spent non-billable work hours (numbers in E) or billable (numbers in E) hours of work.

```
=query(E35:G232, "select G, sum(E), sum(F) where G != '' group by G order by sum(F) desc label G 'activity', sum(E) 'work hours', sum(F) 'billable hours'")
```

So this might give me:

```
Development |  5 | 12
Marketing   | 14 |  5
Admin       |  0 |  2
```

What I've tried, but so far failed, to do now is getting this same list with the combined hours per activity, and also sort it by that combined number. I tried combining the select with combining the sum of columns, but that gives me an error:

```
=query(E35:G232, "select G, sum(E), sum(F), sum(E:F) where ...
```

How can I further combine the grouped values to get the overall values per activity to get something like this, additionally sorted by highest combined?

```
Marketing   | 14 |  5 | 19
Development |  5 | 12 | 17
Admin       |  0 |  2 |  2
```

Comment: You can't. Use a double query: `=query(query())`

Comment: Or just add a formula next to the query results

Comment: @I'-'I Can you give me an example? I suppose the subquery would be generating a col of combined values in this case?

Comment: @Rubén The query affects the sorting, and I would like to sort all 4 columns in rows with combined hours highest. Can a formula do that, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a double query like:

```
=QUERY(query(E35:G232, "select G, sum(E), sum(F) where G != '' group by G order by sum(F) desc label G 'activity', sum(E) 'work hours', sum(F) 'billable hours'"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col2+Col3 order by Col2+Col3",1 )
```

Comment: Impressive. So you can use one query to generate a new data source "on the fly", then use a query on that data to do the summation and sorting. One question though, are those *Col1*, *Col2*, etc. special syntax referring to a query result? I can't find any documentation where to read up more on this.

Comment: @kontur If the input to query is a range in a sheet,We use column identifiers(A,B,E,..). If not,We use numbers,Col1,Col2 ..